# Compiling Tesseract OCR library for Android Studio

Tags: android, tesseract, tess-two

I am still confused about how to build a working `tess-two Android Studio` project for using Tesseract OCR, despite several posts on it. There is a pre-built version available, whose "Usage" section of the "ReadMe" says we can do this by simply adding `tess-two` as an external dependency by just adding the following line to the `dependencies` section of our app's `build.gradle`:

```
compile 'com.rmtheis:tess-two:6.0.3'
```

I understand this tells `Android Studio` to fetch the pre-built version of the library from the remote `Maven` repository where it has been published, **but** do we **still** need to copy across into our fresh new `Android Studio` project the **contents** of the `tess-two` directory that we download or clone?

Please see the attached **image**: My new blank **Android Studio** project is called **TessAndroid**. Elsewhere, I have saved the complete `tess-two` contents after downloading the zip file. In addition to the `compile` line added to the `dependencies` section of my app's `build.gradle`, do I **also** have to copy the **tess-two** folder (or some parts of it) into my main app's root directory?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In addition to the compile line added to the dependencies section of my app's build.gradle, do I also have to copy the tess-two folder (or some parts of it) into my main app's root directory?

No. By adding that `compile` line to your build.gradle, you're importing a compiled version of that library's code into your project, and there's no need to also copy its source code into your project.

You can confirm this yourself by creating a new project in Android Studio, adding the `compile` line for the library to your new app's build.gradle, and then adding a line of code to your new activity's `onCreate` method that references a class in the library:

```
TessBaseAPI baseApi = new TessBaseAPI();
```

The class will be found and usable within your project.